# Avoiding Float Text Wrapping

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

[image]

My code is below:

HTML

```
<li class="bingo-offer">
                <ul>
                    <li class="bingo-offer-image"><img src="../img/winkbingo-146.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li><h3>Wink Bingo</h3></li>
                    <li>Free Cash: <span>£20</span></li>
                    <li>Join one of the biggest Bingo sites on the Internet and enjoy a whopping £20 bonus when you deposit £5!</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="play-btn">Play Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="read-more">read more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

CSS

```
.bingo-offer {
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
    .bingo-offer ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
    }
        .bingo-offer ul li.bingo-offer-image {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
            .bingo-offer ul li.bingo-offer-image img {
                display: block;
            }
            .bingo-offer ul li .play-btn {
                background: url('../img/play-button.png') top left no-repeat;
                text-indent: 100%;
                white-space: nowrap;
                display: block;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 68px;
                height: 24px;
            }
            .bingo-offer ul li a.read-more {
                color: #ee00f7;
                border-bottom: dotted 1px #f45ffa;
                font-size: 11px;
            }
        .bingo-offer ul li h3 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: #ee00f7;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
```

I have something similar, but the entire text to the right is wrapping around the image when the text length goes beyond that of the hight of the image. How can I stop this? I'd like to do it without including any unsemantic code if possible.

Currently all I am floating the image left.

Comment: What part of this are you asking about exactly?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the CSS

Comment: And your CSS? Add it also. Btw you really need that ul > li structure or we can change it?

Comment: which text is wrapping around the image. Float does that

Comment: The entire text to the right of the image.

Comment: float the entire text right. wrap all the text in a separate dv or ul and float it right with the image floated left. Than clear your floats

Comment: @Jawad I was thinking about doing that, but I can remember I did it a simpler way few years back, totally forgot how to do it though.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle please. it should be easy enough with your current markup. But it is the way float is supposed to work. If the text runs long enough around a left floated image the EXTRA text will wrap around the image and proballay fall below it. But you will have to also decide what to do with the EXTRA text. I mean it has to go somewhere or disappear using the overflow property.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rxQQb/

Comment: You must set a width on floated elements. In this fiddle I just made the img large. You can just float all your text right and set width on them with out using extra div or ul. Or you could use the positioning properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612997/css-disable-text-wrapping-around-floating-images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411219/css-to-stop-text-wrapping-under-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456678/stopping-text-from-wrapping-around-image

Comment: http://ghettocooler.net/2005/11/13/image-floats-without-the-text-wrap/

Comment: http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-fix-wrapping-text-around-floated-elements